# How to retain gridview data when postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have fill data in grid view.   And also i have written in code inside  Row Data Bound for changing image URL to image.

Here is the code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)

 {
    for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
      string cellValue = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Trim();
      if(cellValue.StartsWith("http:"))
      {
           System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
           img.ImageUrl = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Trim();
           HyperLink hb = new HyperLink();
           hb.Controls.Add(img);
           e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(hb);
     }
    }        
 }
```

It is working fine.  The page has another two drop down controls.  If i select one drop down control, i made post back.  At that time,  the image inside i already wrote is changed to URL instead of Image.

Can you any one assist me to handle?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code for the issues(i am not able to post entire code)

aspx code:

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <form id="form1" runat="server">

 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" CssClass="borderradius" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="190px" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged" Font-Size="11px">

 </asp:DropDownList> 

 <asp:Button id="sidesbmt" runat="server" onclick="sidesbmt_click"/>                    
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr"

AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"

BorderStyle="None" GridLines="Both">

<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle>

  </asp:GridView>
</body>
 </html>
```

Code Behind

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

 {
 }
 protected void sidesbmt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
  GridView1.DataSource = ds;

  GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)

 {
     for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
     {
        string cellValue = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Trim();
        if(cellValue.StartsWith("http:"))
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
            img.ImageUrl = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Trim();
            HyperLink hb = new HyperLink();
            hb.Controls.Add(img);
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(hb);
        }
     }        
 }
```

Comment: What's in your page load? Add if(!IsPostback){ ... } in your page load

Comment: I have written databinding inside button click not in page load.....

Comment: Please post the entire code aspx and code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem happens when you add controls dynamically and this control does not exist during the Page Init event. To restore the viewstate to the control after postback, the control has to be present in the control tree.

You can try changing your code a bit like this.
Conver the column which displays the image and url into template field

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="literalUrl" Text='<%#Eval("The fieldname")%>'></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="imageUrl" Visible="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in the rowdatabound event toggle the view of image and literal

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        string cellValue = e.Row.Cells[i].Text.Trim();
        Literal literal = e.Row.Cells[i].FindControl("literalUrl") as Literal;
        Image imageUrl = e.Row.Cells[i].FindControl("imageUrl") as Image;
        if (literal != null && imageUrl != null)
        {
            if (literal.Text.StartsWith("http:"))
            {
                imageUrl.ImageUrl = literal.Text.Trim();
                imageUrl.Viisible = true;
                literal.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```